# win64\debug\dsnap.dcp appears to be outdated

Tags: delphi, datasnap, win64, delphi-run-time-library

When compiling my runtime libs with Rad studio Tokyo 10.2.3 I get a 'package dsnap needs to be recompiled' error if a package or exe actually depends on it.

I found out it is due to the dsnap.dcp in my `$(BDSLIB)\win64\debug` folder. The workaround is to copy the dsnap.dcp from the corresponding release folder to the debug folder.
I did make a copy of the original file.

**The question** 
Can anyone with delphi 10.2.3 verify this file matches theirs ? Embarcadero is a bit slow on responding...

- dsnap.dcp
- dated 8 dec 2017
- size 1.128.136 bytes
- original location `C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\Studio\19.0\lib\win64\debug\dsnap.dcp`

**Why the question**? If not a match, something obviously went wrong with my upgrade installation). Also reported as [RSP-20723](https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-20723) where you can get the actual file. (Unfortunately I do not know yet how to do a file attachment here)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have checked in several installations and it seems that dsnap.dcp is missing coompletely in win64\debug. Obviously this is an error in the setup.

Your outdated dsnap.dcp is probably a leftover from a previous installation failed to be deleted during the update.

As the library path contains win64\release anyway, it should be sufficient to just delete dsnap.dcp from win64\debug instead of keeping a copy there. That might pave the ground for a further update bringing the debug version back (not sure if this will actually happen).

Answer (score 0):

Answer provided on the embarcadero quality site in response to my reported issue [RSP-20723](https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-20723), dsnap.dcp is missing from the lib\win64\debug folder. So I am pretty sure it is a left-over from my previous RAD studio installation, and obvoulsy didnt get do be deleted during uninstallation for a yet unknown reason.

FYI: The answer was kindly provided by Uwe Raabe on the issue itself, not by Embarcadero...

Comment: That answer is not from Embarcadero.

Comment: Uwe, if you answer here, I'll favourite it. and drop my own answer.